# State not reactive with Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to decrement or increment a cart in Vuex when I click, but the change doesn't reflect until I re-render the component or click "commit" again in the devtools for Vue.

What my store looks like:

- state

```js
state: {
  toggleSideBar: false,
  cart: [],
},
```

- Action

```js
action:{
  incrementCart: ({ commit }, payload) => {
  commit("INCREMENT_CART", payload);
},
 addToCart: ({ commit, state }, payload) => {
      commit("ADD_TO_CART", payload);
    },
}
```

- mutation

```js
mutation:{
INCREMENT_CART(state, payload) {
  let index = state.cart.findIndex((x) => x.id === payload);
  state.cart[index].amount += 1;
},
  ADD_TO_CART(state, payload) {
      let amount = 1;
      if (state.cart.length === 0) {
        payload.amount = amount;
        return state.cart.push(payload);
      } else {
        if (state.cart.some((cart) => cart.id === payload.id)) {
          let index = state.cart.findIndex((x) => x.id === payload.id);
          state.cart[index].amount += amount;
        } else {
          payload.amount = amount;
          state.cart.push(payload);
        }
      }
    },
}
```

---

- then in my component

```js
computed: {
  cartData() {
    return this.$store.state.cart;
    console.log(this.$store.state.cart);
  },
}
```

In which the value is then passed as props to individual cart

Comment: carData() is in computed or in method ? can you put more code well formatted ?

Comment: please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63404747/vue-js-vuex-updating-an-object-within-an-array-inside-state-not-reflected-in-co/63404757#63404757

Comment: You're running into reactivity issues: if the item at `index` does not exist in cart, then you cannot set it as such: you will need to use `Vue.set`

Comment: Vue.set(state.cart, index, {...state.cart, amount : state.cart.amount +1})

Comment: @robert will this go into mutations? if yes I did and was still getting the same result;

I also added new items to my questions up there, on ADD_TO_CART mutation, maybe that could be the origin of my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a getter in your Vuex like so:

```
getters: {
    getCart(state) {
        return state.cart;
    }
}
```

And then in your computed you need to call your getter like this:

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
    
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(['getCart']);
    }
}
```

And finally in your html tag you need to call your getter like so:

```
<div v-for="item in getCart">item.quantity</div>
```